# flutter commands can't run in command prompt on windows 11

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

any time I input a flutter command in cmd, a new window for the prompt opens and closes quickly and then returns to the old prompt asking me to input a new command without having any effect from the old command. for example...flutter create 'appname' doesn't run but returns asking me to input a command.
i have set my paths and everything too

Comment: Make sure you've setup correctly the ``PATH` in Eniviromental Variables

Comment: share screenshot too

Comment: could you share which doc you followed to install flutter and also PATH you set for flutter?